# Aptana 3 Javascript Syntax Validator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, validation, aptana, aptana3

I've installed Aptana 3 right now but the Javascript Syntax Validator doesn't work. What i'm doing wrong? I've testet the JSLint & Javascript Style Validator and they are working..

[image: Aptana Javscript Syntax Validator]

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the `Javascript Syntax Validator`, you will notice that it's empty by default.

That's why.

Comment: hmm yeah it is. but i've don't changed anything and restore defaults doesn't work too.